# Update mysql record

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Hello I want to update value when it appear in database twice and more. I have this code but it doesn't work.

Tahts how I add records.

```
global $wpdb;
 $prefix = $wpdb->prefix.searchmeter ;
 $search_terms = $_GET['s'];
 $query = "INSERT INTO  `$prefix`  (`terms`,`date`,`count`)
           VALUES ('$search_terms',CURDATE(),1) 
           ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `count` = `count`+1 ";       
 $success = $wpdb->query($query);
```

here is how I display it

```
<?php 

              $results = $wpdb->get_results(
              "SELECT `terms`, `count`
              FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}searchmeter`
              WHERE DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 30 DAY ) <= `date` AND count > 15                         
              GROUP BY `terms`
              ORDER BY count DESC, `terms` ASC");              


              echo "<ul class='wp-tag-cloud'>";                
              foreach ($results as $result) {
                echo '<li><a href="?s='.$result->terms.'">'. $result->terms .'</a></li>'."\n";
              }
              echo "</ul>";              
              ?>
```

I have this data

```
terms | data | count
list    15.03   1
```

When I have duplicate key count should be 2 but is like this

```
terms | data | count
list    15.03   3
```

Comment: Do you get some errors?

Comment: No but I'm checking if it's complete with simple if statement and it says that code wont complete.

Comment: I see you used VALUES('count'+1) instead of VALUES(\`count\`+1). Try to change that and see if it helps

Comment: @ErnestNowacki Still doesn't work.

Comment: You can also try to change the line to ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE \`count\`= \`count\` + 1;

Comment: Look at first post edited I have this and now query adds to record 2 insted of 1 someone know why?

Comment: Ok now your syntax is correct. If you're getting 2 records it might be caused by lack of unique index on one of your columns (terms, date)

Comment: How can I check which one of them is unique?

Answer (score 0):

try that

```
   global $wpdb;
 $prefix = $wpdb->prefix.searchmeter ;
 $search_terms = $_GET['s'];
 $query = "INSERT INTO  `$prefix`  (`terms`,`date`,`count`)
           VALUES ('$search_terms',CURDATE(),1)
           ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `count` = `count`+1 ";       
 $success = $wpdb->query($query);
```